# My mint tea tastes like a weed

Tags: mint, tea

I made some mint tea and it tastes more like a weed then tea?

Using this [recipe](https://www.artfulhomemaking.com/how-to-make-mint-tea/) from artfulhomemaking.com

> How to Make Mint Tea with
> Fresh Mint
>
> This is a delicious and refreshing summer drink that is easy to make!
>
> Ingredients
>
> - 1 large handful of fresh mint sprigs (include leaves and stems)
> - 5 cups room temperature water
> - 1 cup boiling water
> - 1/3 tsp pure stevia extract (or sweetener of choice-honey works well too)
>
> lnstructions
>
> 1. Gather a very large handful of fresh mint leaves. lf you want your tea stronger,
>    use two handfuls of leaves.
> 2. Rinse the freshly picked mint with clean water.
> 3. Put rinsed mint in a large bowl and add 6 cups of clean, room temperature
>    water.
> 4. Crush the mint with your clean hands until the water turns a brownish color.
> 5. Strain through a fine nresh strainer or a cloth into a gallon jar.
> 6. Boil 1 cups of water (I use my electric kettle for this) and pour over the
>    crushed mint leaves that are still in the bowl that you just strained). Let the
>    mint leaves steep in the boiled water for 10-15 minutes {just cover the bowl
>    with a plate to let it steep).
>    7, Add steeped mint tea to the gallon jar with the rest of the tea. Add your
>    sweetener of choice (I use stevia or honey), and stir well to combine. Add
>    clean water to the jar until you have about a gallon of tea.
> 7. Add ice cubes to the tea to help it cool down faster. Serve over ice, and enjoy

Comment: If you're referring specifically to *iced* mint tea, please edit the title and first paragraph to say so.  Mint tea is commonly served hot, in which case it's usually made in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 5):

Check your mint, as not all mints taste good.

- Avoid Orange Mint, which smells minty and tastes like orange-zested peppermint dirt.
  [image]
- Chocolate mint? Not in tea, either.
- A similar fooler is the wine-colored Chocolate Cosmos which smells like
  chocolate but only after it's been through a cow.
- Steep less. The long steeping brings out the woody flavor of the stems — more black-tea-like and less bright mint. Steep for one minute, and remove mint (compost!).
- Seriously, the recipe needs 6 times the sweetener. Stevia, okay. Orange Blossom honey, yes. Agave, excellent and lower-glycemic.

Comment: Mint tea is often completely unsweetened, so your last point is very much a matter of taste

Comment: Applemint varieties are supposed to be good for tea.  I don't drink mint tea but the Bowles Mint I grow goes down well with those who do.  But that's hot, made simply by rinsing then steeping for a couple of minutes in hot water, a few big leaves to a cup.